# Why does the Ark burn the markings off its crate?

Tags: plot-explanation, indiana-jones, raiders-of-the-lost-ark

In *Raiders of the Lost Ark*, while the Ark is sitting inside a crate in the ship's hold we are shown that the crate mysteriously starts to burn, obscuring the swastika and other markings stenciled on its side.

Presumably it's the Ark itself that is doing this, since no one is around at the time.

[image: crate being burned]

Why does the Ark burn the crate? It evidently doesn't hinder the Germans finding it when they intercept the cargo ship shortly thereafter. The Ark's crate appears to be the only thing in the cargo hold.

[image: crate by itself in the cargo hold]

[image: crate with the lettering burned]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no commentary from the film-makers (that I can find) that covers this **specific** burning crate subject but it seems evident that it's...

### ..because the Ark refuses to be marked by *evil* which is represented by the Nazi markings.

Nazi symbols take quite a beating or are mocked *a lot* in the movie and this is just another example...albeit with more visceral impact.

Others include...

- A Nazi flag is used as a rope
- Indy breaks off the Nazi hood ornament of the car (IIRC)
- A monkey gives a Nazi salute

Comment: But it also burns off the US Army markings when it is stored away in the warehouse at the end. I don't think Spielberg would quite consider them "evil." Misguided, maybe.

Comment: [**There is no such scene**](https://www.cbr.com/movie-legends-revealed-alternate-ending-for-raiders-of-the-lost-ark/)

Comment: Paulie_D's comment is in reference to @ScottyParker's comment, about the ark burning off US Army markings (which never happens in the movie).

Comment: Yeah. It's in the working script, but did not make it into the final cut.

Comment: If you have evidence of that...please present it.

Answer (score -3):

Mere mortals aren't meant to possess the Ark as a weapon. It is to be revered, feared and obeyed.

Spielberg doesn't do director's commentary, so I'm looking for references from interviews that might support that angle.

Comment: This isn't really an answer - can you provide some more detailed analysis or supporting references for this?

Comment: Actually, the very purpose of the Ark was to be possessed by mere mortals.  It was created to hold the Commandments.